# User authentication is not persisted on WebView

Tags: android, firebase, webview, firebase-authentication, firebase-hosting

I'm creating an Android app that has a WebView which accesses my website hosted using Firebase Hosting.

If I sign into the website using email/password credentials and then refresh or navigate to another page, Firebase loses my login information.

I tried to force Firebase to keep my credentials using `firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL)` but it throws this error in the WebView console:

> Uncaught Error: The current environment does not support the specified persistence type.

As a side note, I tried logging in on other services, such as YouTube and Google to see if it was a browser cache problem, but the session was persisted normally, even after I refreshed the page, navigated or reopened the Android app.

I also tested the Android app using the emulator (running Android 8.0) and a phone (Android 6.0).

Does somebody know what's going on here?

Comment: Are you using `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` to get the Auth state?

Comment: @bojeil Yes I am

Comment: Did you disable web storage in the webview? is localStorage enabled?

Comment: I'll check that when I get home. But I'm pretty sure I didn't disable anything. Just followed the example from this page: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/gettingstarted

Comment: I haven't done a lot of android development recently but I used to have to enable it on a webview: `webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that later. The only thing I'm curious about is that in other websites my login is persisted normally. Could that behavior be intentional from Firebase?

Comment: @bojeil I just tested it and it works now! Please, make an answer with this piece of code so I can chose it as the correct one.

Comment: Glad it worked. I added my answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to enable DOM storage in your webview as Firebase Auth depends on web storage (localStorage/indexedDB) to store the Auth state.

`webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);`